Will the product of electrolysis of all dilute aqueous solutions be hydrogen or oxygen?
According to my book, the electrolysis of some dilute solutions give hydrogen and oxygen because the concentration of other elements is very low. So, does this apply to all dilute solutions?

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that.// Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

What is electrolysed is determined by the voltages for each species present and the Nernst equation for each species present. It is probably safe to say that in aqueous solution H2 and O2 are always produced in competition to other possible reactions. As other reducible ions are lowered production of H2 becomes more likely, likewise for oxidizable ions water and OH- are always present to give O2.
